# My strings contains " and ' how to deal with it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

In my code, I have a string that contains `"` and `'` in between how to deal with it?

And it is randomly generated every time I generate a string at different positions and gives me an error when I try to print due to `"` or `'` it marks as the end of some strings and the post characters of that string generate an error.

**Edit 1:**
An example for such type of string is:

```
85)p$85"5p9p1=p%#9>7p'81$#1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an example of such a string?

Comment: Yes edited my ques with an example string please check.

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? If it's randomly generated every time, it'll already be in a variable and printing it should be no problem. Can you post a short code example that's failing for you?

Comment: Please [edit] to show how you are printing it such strings or variables, and what exact error do you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape it using the `\`. If your string starts with double quote, then escape `\'` and escape `\"` if starts with single one.